# Getting error when running composer install on CRAFT CMS project on Windows

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, craftcms

Setup: Windows 10, PHP 8.0.2, composer 2.1.6

I cloned a project from bitbucket and ran composer install.

After Running the command I got the error bellow.

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - ibericode/vat is locked to version 1.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - ibericode/vat 1.2.1 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
  Problem 2
    - ibericode/vat 1.2.1 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
    - craftcms/commerce 3.4.2 requires ibericode/vat ^1.1.2 -> satisfiable by ibericode/vat[1.2.1].
    - craftcms/commerce is locked to version 3.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I tried running composer update, but I was presented wit h a similar error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - ibericode/vat[1.1.2, ..., 1.2.1] require ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
    - craftcms/commerce 3.4.2 requires ibericode/vat ^1.1.2 -> satisfiable by ibericode/vat[1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.0, 1.2.1].
    - Root composer.json requires craftcms/commerce 3.4.2 -> satisfiable by craftcms/commerce[3.4.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Steps that I tried:

- enable soap extension in php.ini
- confirm that php_soap.dll is in the php extension folder php/ext
- restart the machine

But that didn't help.

Then I tried the answer provided in https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/30270

That didn't help either.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093941/composer-install-update-errors-craft-cms - how did you ensure that `ext-soap` is **really** active? Does phpinfo list it?

Comment: I just checked with `php -i` and `php -m` and there is no soap listed.
I also changed extension_dir in php.ini from extension_dir="ext" to extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext" and restarted the local machine, but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, if that extension is not install, why don't you do that? The error message is pretty clear about that...

Comment: I searched on the web how to do that... It all comes to checking if php_soap.dll is in <php folder>\ext and uncommenting extension=soap.
And still no success.

But I went through XAMPP shell and there it worked like a charm (after I enabled it in php.ini). So problem solved, but the original issue remains (and that's bugging me).

In any case, thank you. The first comment pointed me in the right direction. :)